# How i can manually send req and response object in this listen function of connector in Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, botframework, bots

I want to dynamically set a listener for a request on the basis of params passed?

```
app.post(/asd/message,connector.liten());
```

want to do?

```
app.post(/asd/message/:parameter,function(req, resp,next){
     console.log(req.params.parameter);
     resp.send(connector.listen(req,resp));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use express middleware:

```
server.post('/api/messages/:p', [(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.params.p);
    next();
},connector.listen()]);
```